# How can I auto start up Cisco rack server on power restore?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cisco

We have a Cisco C240 M3 v2 server which not auto starting up on power restore. I have been browsing through its BIOS  looking for options like 'power on on power restore'. Our office building at the moment suffering from temporary frequent power outage. So, is there an option for auto powering up for Cisco C240 M3 v2 rack server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.  In the far left column of CIMC, select the server tab.  Select "Power Policy" from the items offered.  The setting is called "Power Restore Policy" which you will want to set to either 'Restore Last State' or 'Power On' depending on your needs.

Here is a link to the relevant Cisco document - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/sw/gui/config/guide/3_0/b_Cisco_UCS_C-series_GUI_Configuration_Guide_301/b_Cisco_UCS_C-series_GUI_Configuration_Guide_201_chapter_011.html#d71727e3886a1635

Comment: Can I start CIMC during startup? Is it different than BIOS?

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed - CIMC starts automatically when the machine is powered up.  It is a system management chip separate from the BIOS.  You can set the IP address for accessing CIMC by pushing F8 during the post process. https://community.cisco.com/t5/data-center-documents/configure-or-change-cimc-ip-address-on-ucs-c200-series-servers/ta-p/3141563

Comment: I cant seem to find any option saying 'power policy' inside CIMC.

Comment: Which version of the CIMC / system firmware are you on?

Comment: it appears to v2.0 like this version in the page: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/servers-unified-computing/unified-computing-system/200221-Auto-negotiation-not-enabling-by-default.html

Comment: Here is the user guide for CIMC v2.  I don't have a 2.0 machine around to check these out on, so I hope that this guide gets you to what you are looking for.  There is also a command line interface for CIMC that you could use to input more directly - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/sw/gui/config/guide/2-0/b_Cisco_UCS_C-series_GUI_Configuration_Guide_201/b_Cisco_UCS_C-series_GUI_Configuration_Guide_201_chapter_011.html#d91029e3756a1635

Comment: How can I access this CIMC CLI? I have figured out commands I need for setting up power policy in CIMC CLI docs. My system saying CIMC IP: 192.168.1.2. But I can find nothing during browsing at http://192.168.1.2. During startup, I only can access a `Preboot CLI` which can not recognize any of my SCOPE commands.

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed - does your server have a separate Mgmt / CIMC ethernet port on it?  I don't recall if the C240 servers had an option for sharing the CIMC port or if it's always standalone.  Have you tried telnet & ssh both against that IP address?

Comment: Server is on Windows Server 2012 r2 OS. It is running no ssh server at the moment. Is there any BIOS level ssh service?

Comment: Yes, the CIMC chip runs both an HTTP service and a SSH service.  The CIMC is accessed entirely separately from the operating system(s) that you install on the server.  The basic idea is that you need to set a CIMC IP address (or DHCP) and then access that IP via a browser or SSH - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/sw/cli/config/guide/1-4-1/b_Cisco_UCS_C-Series_CLI_Configuration_Guide_141/b_Cisco_UCS_C-Series_CLI_Configuration_Guide_141_chapter_01.html

Comment: OK. So, if my CIMC IP is 192.168.1.2 and my server is up and running, I should be able to access CIMC by navigating to http://192.168.1.2 on a web browser on my server?

Comment: Yes, provided that the CIMC ethernet port has a good connection.  Also you probably need to point at https

Comment: So, connecting an ethernet wire from servers CIMC port to my laptop would enable me to ssh to server CIMC from my laptop `ssh usernm@192.168.1.2` right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to make that work.  Or you attach the CIMC port to a switch and access it over the LAN.

Comment: I have found out my server NIC mode supports only `Shared LOM` in BIOS CIMC at the moment. Would CIMC be accessible from my laptop having static IP address 192.168.100.xxx over LAN?

Comment: It should be, at least with proper settings (IP, gateway, etc.).  The goal of the CIMC access port is just like any other Mgmt ethernet port on a device.

Comment: Ok. I can now access CIMC. I have connected my CIMC port to my server switch via ethernet cable. I've setup IP+default admin pass and now I'm able to access CIMC on my browser. But still server not auto starting up on power restore. I am testing it by turning server UPS off and back on. Am I missing something?

Comment: What value is your "Power Restore Policy" setting?  What CIMC version?

Comment: My 'power restore policy' is set to 'Power On'. CIMC Version: 2.0(8d)

Comment: That should be it then.  I tested mine and it works, the only thing I'm left with is to recommend that you get up-to-date on your BIOS / CIMC firmware, what you're running is quite out-of-date.